# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol can not track cart addition and product view

Tags: django, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-docs, measurement-protocol

I have implemented a measurement protocol in my project. I can successfully track purchases, checkouts, pageviews and refunds.
For example, by sending this data with some additions from function outside I can track purchase events.

```
 data = {
        't': 'pageview',
        'ti': '123123',     
        'tr': 1510,
        'ts': 10,
        'cu': 'GEL',
        'pa': 'purchase',
        'cid': request.COOKIES.get('client_id'),
        'pr1id': '123123',
        'pr1nm': 'iPhoneXR',
        'pr1ca': 'Smartphones',
        'pr1pr': 500,
        'pr1br': 'Apple',
        'pr1va': 'RED 128 GB',
        'pr1qt': 2
    }
```

Now I am struggling to track product views and cart additions and I have gone through whole measurement protocol parameters and common hits that was shown in the documentation but could not find a solution. Any ideas on how can I track cart additions and product views?

Answer (score 1):

You have set *Product Action* with a value *purchase*. The other available value options are detail, click, add, remove, checkout, checkout_option and refund.

You may want to try *add* instead. I am referring to Google API documentation at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#pa